# Do I have to use firebase-redux firestore-redux to connect redux to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I already managed to connect firebase and firestore with redux without using firebase-redux and firestore-redux packages. What differences does it make to using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those packages are their own opinionated integrations of the two libraries. If you agree with their opinions then they'll save you setup time, if you've already set things up and don't need them then adding them is unecessary.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I wasn’t sure if the packages were original firebase and necessary for running firebase on redux. Thanks for clarification